# Combine rows when a person has more than one race, to a single row called Two or more Races

Tags: sql, oracle

Some students within my district have more than one race. I am trying to create a column in Oracle SQL with the students race but I am getting multiple rows for one student because the student has more than one race. I want to combine them into one row called Two or more races. Here is a little example:

```
Select 
student_number,
race
```

| Student_Number | Race |
| --- | --- |
| 5144 | White |
| 5144 | Asian |

Any idea on how I could combine them into one row, or is that more something you would do in Python.

Comment: The request would bebefit from you showing table data for two students, one with only one race, one with two races, plus a table with the expected result.

Comment: I've tagged your request `oracle`. This helps getting people who know the Oracle database for help. Always tag SQL requests with your DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] Considering the solution from [@Thorsten Kettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270762/thorsten-kettner), to take account of `NULL` values just add the [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreffunccoalesce.html) clause on the `race` field:

```sql
SELECT
  student_number,
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(COALESCE(race, 'Unkown')) = MAX(COALESCE(race, 'Unkown'))
      THEN  MIN(COALESCE(race, 'Unkown'))
      ELSE 'Two or more races'
  END AS races
FROM students
GROUP BY student_number
ORDER BY student_number;
```

Input:

| student_number | race |
| --- | --- |
| 5144 | White |
| 5144 | Asian |
| 5145 | NULL |
| 5146 | White |

Output:

| student_number | races |
| --- | --- |
| 5144 | Two or more races |
| 5145 | Unknown |
| 5146 | White |

---

However, if you want to aggregate each occurrence of "Race" in a single column named 'Two or more races' (let's say, separated by a comma), you'll need the [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030) function from Oracle:

```sql
SELECT
  student_number,
  LISTAGG(COALESCE(race, 'Unkown'),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY student_number) "Two or more races"
FROM students
GROUP BY student_number;
```

Output:

| student_number | races |
| --- | --- |
| 5144 | Asian, White |
| 5145 | Unknown |
| 5146 | White |

Demo in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/190175/6).

Answer (score 0):

You want aggregation. You'll aggregate your data so as to get one row per student number (`GROUP BY student_number`). Then check whether the minimum race (i.e. first in alphabetical order) equals the maximum one.

```
select 
  student_number,
  case when min(race) = max(race) then min(race) else 'Two or more races' end as races
from mytable
group by student_number
order by student_number;
```

Comment: So, I just realized that the code is not picking up Null values. When I run the code the null values become two or more races, too. How would I account for the null values to be listed as unknown, or just to remain null?

Comment: I didn't know that null values are even possible. You could replace `race` with `COALESCE(race, 'Unknown')` in my query, then nulls would be treated as a race called 'Unknown'. This would work for students with only a null entry. If it is even possible to find a race *and* null for a student, you'll want to ignore the null and things start to get complicated. And is it possible to find a race twice for a student? Well, `COUNT(*)` counts all rows, while `COUNT(race)` only counts non-null races, `COUNT(DISTINCT race)` would ignore duplicates,..

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN race IS NULL THEN 1 END)` counts nulls. You can combine what's needed to check the conditions that lead to the single race, 'Two or more races' or 'Race unknown'. Maybe you need `AND` / `OR`, maybe you need multiple `WHEN`. I guess I have given you all the information you need to get this done.